# Generate array PHP from MySQL table

Tags: php, arrays

I have this table, resulting from a SELECT + INNER && LEFT JOIN (this is the spiegation of the NULL values).

```
cookery         id_cookery  detail       id_detail
Locale          1            NULL        NULL
Regionale       2            NULL        NULL
Regionale       2            Abruzzese   1
Nazionale       3            NULL         NULL
Internazionale  4            NULL         NULL
Internazionale  4            Africana    3
Internazionale  4            Americana   82
```

My framework put this result in this array:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cookery] => Locale
                    [id_cookery] => 1
                    [detail] => 
                    [id_detail] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [cookery] => Regionale
                    [id_cookery] => 2
                    [detail] => 
                    [id_detail] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [cookery] => Regionale
                    [id_cookery] => 2
                    [detail] => Abruzzese
                    [id_detail] => 1
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [cookery] => Nazionale
                    [id_cookery] => 3
                    [detail] => 
                    [id_detail] => 
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [cookery] => Internazionale
                    [id_cookery] => 4
                    [detail] => 
                    [id_detail] => 
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [cookery] => Internazionale
                    [id_cookery] => 4
                    [detail] => Africana
                    [id_detail] => 3
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [cookery] => Internazionale
                    [id_cookery] => 4
                    [detail] => Americana
                    [id_detail] => 82
                )

        )
```

By the way, I need to create an array with this aspect, grouping the "cookery" in only 4 field (Locale, Regionale, Nazionale and Internazionale) and IF the cookery has "detail", putting them sub his key.

A sort of:

```
Array (locale => '',
regionale => Abruzzese
nazionale => '',
Internazionale => Africana, Americana)
```

(probably I did not write correctly this Array, but I hope that you understand).

1) I tried first of all to save in a temp array only the different id_cookery, to use later

```
 if (!in_array($value['id_cookery'],$tmp))
            {
                $tmp[] = $value['id_cookery']);
            }
```

But sincerly I don't know what I can do with it...

2) I tried to save in another array only the values != NULL

```
if ($value['detail']!='')
                {
                    $temp[$key][] = $value['cookery'];
                    $temp[$key][] = $value['detail'];
                    $temp[$key][] = $value['id_cookery'];
                }
```

But at this time... How I can merge the arrays and obtain my goal? Or can you help, following any road?

Thank you very, very much.

PS How I can post a mysql table to view correctly? I saw in others answer that posted Mysql table seems a jpeg from terminal... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$answer = array();

//Loop your rows here

if(false == array_key_exists($value['cookery'], $answer)){
    $answer[$value['cookery']] = array();
}

if($value['detail'] != null && false == array_key_exists($value['detail'], $answer[$value['cookery']])){
    $answer[$value['cookery']][] = $value['cookery']
}

//end loop here
```

Note: This will allow not allow duplicate values in the detail.

However, this results in

```
Array (locale => Array(),
regionale => Array(Abruzzese),
nazionale => Array(),
Internazionale => Array(Africana, Americana))
```

I would then change them to a string (if that is what you desire with an implode loop.

```
$finalAnswer = array();
foreach($answer as $key => $answerEntry){
    $finalAnswer[$key] = implode(",",$answerEntry);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Only to change $answer[$value['cookery']][] = $value['cookery'] with $answer[$value['cookery']][] = $value['detail']; Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want something like this:

```
$input = your framework array;
$output = array();
foreach($input as $row){
    if(!isset($output[$row['cookery']])){
        $output[$row['cookery']] = array();
    }
    if($row['detail']){
        $output[$row['cookery']][] = $row['detail'];
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

PS. the screenshots are actualy done in a terminal! They use the mysql command line

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated :)

Comment: yeah... sometimes relying on frameworks "detaches" you from real world :)

Comment: You must forgive me. I'm using a framework and it extract from mysql with the array that I ve posted just now. Please look at the edited question. Thank you!

Comment: Edited to use an array as input :)